# Rotating jquery UI slider does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am creating slider as below

```
$("#slider1V").slider({orientation : "vertical",min : 0,max : 100});
```

i am applying css

```
#slider1V {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

after applying css the slider does not slide properly 
Its very hard to drag the handle
The internal dragger does not get transformed
how can i make it smooth

please anyone can help me out

[JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/pareshmutha1900/ra42v1tf/)

Comment: All the jqueryui widgets that rely on positioning seem to have a strong dislike for `transform`s so this shouldn't come as a surprise. Could you make [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Your fiddle says: `TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function`

Comment: please check i have updated

Comment: Can you please specify with an image what output you would expect from this?

Answer (score 0):

Why to rotate it if you can change swap and have same effect? jQuery UI is conflicting with your `transform` css.

Instead of

```
#slider1V {
    height: 132px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

use

```
#slider1V {
    height: 10px;
    width: 132px;

    /* removed transform */
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ra42v1tf/1/)

Comment: i have many slider some are horizontal and some are vertical and on orientation change i gave to make horzontal to vertical and vertical to horizontal some are working with your solution but some work in reverse way so ...

Comment: @pareshm So why not use different classes? Maybe you have positioned them differently or maybe initial position is at max?

Comment: I have tried all the possibilities but its working in reverse way

Comment: what code should i put all the code i have given only there are 4 sliders 3 are horizontal and 1 is vertical

Comment: @pareshm copy code to JSFiddle and show that "reverse in action"

Comment: how to do the same thing for -80deg without css

Answer (score 0):

Split out height/width into their own classes

```
#slider1V
{
      position: relative;
      left:20%;
      float: left;
      top: 30px;        
 }

.sliderVertical
{
      width: 132px;
      height: 10px;
}

.sliderHorizontal
{
      width: 132px;
      height: 10px;
}
```

Then for horizontal

```
$("#slider1V").slider({ orientation: "horizontal" });
$("#slider1V").addClass("sliderHorizontal");
```

and vertical

```
$("#slider1V").slider({ orientation: "vertical" });
$("#slider1V").addClass("sliderVertical");
```

See jsfiddler for working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/msully725/ra42v1tf/5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:
Have a look on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37ummyde/1/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#slider1V").slider({
            orientation : 'vertical',
                animate: true,
            min : 0,
            max : 100
    });

    });
    </script>
    <div id="slider1V"></div>
```

Comment: you have not rotated the slider using css

Comment: I bit confused you have applied orientation:'vertical' and after that you are applying transform: rotate(90deg); why you are doing so ?  @pareshm

Comment: If you want to transform it to horizontal slider you can do that by changing orientation:'vertical' to orientation:'horizontal'

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add `transform` once the slider is created using [create event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create) like so

```
$("#slider1V").slider({
    orientation : "vertical",
    min : 0,
    max : 100,
    create: function( event, ui ) { $(this).css('transform','rotate(38deg)') }
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z890fkw4/).

Comment: when i do the same thing for 85 degrees it doe not works properly

Comment: can you post the jsfiiddle for the same